# Routes won't work when I install composer and use autoloading option?

Tags: php, .htaccess, oop, composer-php, autoload

When I install composer and set autoloading option and then click on my links other than home page I get this error  'Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'homeController' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\gacho\app\core\Application.php:13 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\gacho\public\index.php(16): Application->__construct() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\gacho\app\core\Application.php on line 13 ', but link to home page works just fine. Here is my code structure and code:

code structure

```
 gacho
  |-app
     |- controller
     |- core
     |- model
     |- view
  |-public
     |-vendor
       |-composer
          |- autoload_classmap.php
       |- autoload.php
     |- .htaccess
     |- composer.json
     |- index.php
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

composer.json

```
{
  "autoload": {
    "classmap":[
      "../app"
    ]
  }
}
```

autoload_classmap

```
$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
  'App\\Controller\\HomeController' => $baseDir . 
  '/../app/controller/HomeController.php',
  'App\\Core\\Application' => $baseDir . '/../app/core/Application.php',
  'App\\Core\\Controller' => $baseDir . '/../app/core/Controller.php',
  'App\\Core\\Database' => $baseDir . '/../app/core/Database.php',
  'App\\Core\\View' => $baseDir . '/../app/core/View.php',
  'App\\Model\\User' => $baseDir . '/../app/model/User.php',
);
```

index.php

```
define('ROOT', dirname(__DIR__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('APP', ROOT . 'app' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('CONTROLLER', ROOT . 'app' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'controller' . 
DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('VIEW', ROOT . 'app' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'view' . 
DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('MODEL', ROOT . 'app' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'model' . 
DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('CORE', ROOT . 'app' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'core' . 
DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

$modules = [ROOT, APP, CORE, CONTROLLER];

require_once __DIR__ . '\vendor\autoload.php';
new Application;
```

Application.php

```
class Application
{
   protected $controller = 'HomeController';
   protected $action = 'index';
   protected $params = [];

   public function __construct()
   {
      $this->prepareURL();
      if (file_exists(CONTROLLER. $this->controller . '.php')) {
         $this->controller = new $this->controller;
         if (method_exists($this->controller, $this->action)) {
            call_user_func_array([$this->controller, $this->action], $this->params);
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: I don't think its composer issue?  `Uncaught Error: Class 'homeController' not found`
Better check the class name and file name of that class

Comment: @unreleased Yeah, that's it. Thanks. Post it as an answer if you will.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, classmap shows `/../app/controller/HomeController.php`  and your error message showing `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'homeController`.

So please make sure your controller file name and Class Name both are same.
(Wrote the answer as OP requested)